# Powershell: regex replacement with inline calculation

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the files named with `yyyymm` and I need to rename this files with `mmyyyy` but the `mm` in the new name have to be less for a one. And I need to do it inline during the replacement process.

I can do regex replace of the string `abc2017`**`06`**`.txt` to the `abc`**`06`**`2017.txt` with pattern

> `'abc201706.txt' -replace '^(.*)([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})(\..*)$','$1$3$2$4'`

How can I do regex replace to the `abc`**`05`**`2017.txt`?
In other words I need inline subtraction of the one month from `$3` which means the initial month.

I have searched for the answer to my question a lot of posts but without the result. Please do not mark my question as duplicate and answer to it.

Comment: I would do it in several lines, probably without replace. Just `-match` the `basename`, utilize `$matches` and do your calculations. After that, build the basename string again with `-f` operator.

Comment: this is not quite that I need but could you place the example

Answer (score 1):

No beauty, but should work:

```
$myfilepath = 'C:\temp\abc2017 06.txt'
$file = Get-Item $myFilePath -Force 
$basename = $file.basename

$basename -match '^(?<name>\D+)(?<year>\d{4})\s(?<month>\d{2})'

$dateString = "{0}/{1}/01" -f $matches.year, $matches.month
$Datetime = $dateString | Get-Date
$Datetime = $Datetime.AddMonths(-1)

$newBasename = "{0} {1} {2}{3}" -f $matches.name, $Datetime.ToString('MM'), $Datetime.ToString('yyyy'), $file.Extension
```

**update**: Your regex did not match, I changed it a bit.

**Update2**: Write this to a file, and call it however you want.

```
param(
    [string]$myFilePath
)
$file = Get-Item $myFilePath -Force 
$basename = $file.basename

$null = $basename -match '^(?<name>\D+)(?<year>\d{4})\s(?<month>\d{2})'

$dateString = "{0}/{1}/01" -f $matches.year, $matches.month
$Datetime = $dateString | Get-Date
$Datetime = $Datetime.AddMonths(-1)

$newFilename = "{0} {1} {2}{3}" -f $matches.name, $Datetime.ToString('MM'), $Datetime.ToString('yyyy'), $file.Extension

return $newFilename
```

e.g.: ConvertFilename.ps1 -myFilePath "c:\Blah"

Comment: Cool, but I need to make it in one line /

Comment: Well, we could make this a oneliner... but it will be ridicolously long. Why do you need it as a oneliner? What about implementing it as a function?

Comment: hah, of course, I could stretch this code to the one line but it will be absolutely unreadable )

Comment: I need oneline code because I have to call it from another script and it has to be seemed like a such pattern

Comment: The file name patterns vary?

Comment: in other words I have the variable contained the patterns to rename files like this  
> ^something([0-9]{6})\.gz$; another$1.zip
> ^(.*)([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})(\..*)$; $1$3$2$4
and I need to make this replacements by the several methods and one of them is the calling of powershell with string of parameters

Comment: Please give a usable **full** example what your situation is. Seems to me, that you took a path that leads to nothing.

Comment: the parent script is not powershell but Automate (in fact, not native Automate but something derived - EFT server Automate workflow, in short all intricated)

Comment: write this code from the parent script to the external file and run it from the script and capture its output and transfer this output into the variable which use in the parent script to rename the file looks a little bit bulky

Comment: Well, regex cant do math - this code as a oneliner is still huge. So what else can you do? There might be a way to make the code above a bit shortert, but that does not really change a thing. Is there no way to do this in your scripting environment you already use?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use .NET regex [match evaluators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx), basically callback functions that can calculate the replacement value.

Powershell script blocks can be used as match evaluators. They receive the match object as first argument and the value they produce will be used as the replacement.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Name = [Regex]::Replace($_.Name, "(\d{6})(\.txt)$", {
        $match = $args[0]
        try {
            [DateTime]::ParseExact($match.Groups[1], "yyyyMM", $null).AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMyyyy") + $match.Groups[2]
        } catch {
            $match
        }
    })
}
```

The try block attempts to parse the six digits from match group 1 as a DateTime, subtracts a month and puts everything back together again.

The catch block simply outputs the original match in case the conversion to DateTime fails.